# Network request latency

Tags: ios

Apple added `URLSessionTaskMetrics` in iOS 10 which provides quite useful statistics for your network requests. I need to add support for iOS 9, I wonder how best to achieve something similar as URLSessionTaskMetrics.

Comment: Before trying to replicate something thats already out of the box in a later OS i'd consider what percentage of your users are actually using iOS 9. Overall the OS has a very low usage. Easiest thing for you might be to create a new version of the app targeting iOS 10 and just use the inbuilt support

Answer (score 0):

If you're not averse to possibly replacing/augmenting what you've got, I'd try third-party monitoring from New Relic or [Firebase Performance monitoring](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-ios). Hopefully at this point the number of iOS 9 devices your app deals with is small enough that it may not matter though.